# How to prove $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k!}}=:e$

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

I have already proven that $\left(1+\frac 1{n}\right)^n\leq \sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{k!}}$ . Does that help me in any way? I am stumped...

Any suggestions/hints?

Comment: Note that your last equality is not true: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}\neq e.$

Comment: updated. regards, para.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254335/prove-that-5-2-e-3/254339#254339

Comment: You can expand the left hand side using the binomial theorem.

Comment: Are we talking about $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$

Comment: You can calculate the limit of the log.

Comment: This is often taken as the definition of $e$. So what are your premises ?

Comment: How do I prove $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k!}}$, that's my question.

Comment: Do you just need to prove the limit equals that sum, or also that the sum equals $e$.

Comment: Solely that the limit equals the sum.

Comment: basically, why this is true: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_(k%3D0)%5E%E2%88%9E+1%2F(k!)+%3D+lim_(n-%3E%E2%88%9E)+(1+%2B+1%2Fn)%5En

Comment: An "interesting" [take at this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/509638/11619).

Comment: Done here too https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2172435/399263

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n,N\in\mathbb N$, with $n\geqslant N$, then\begin{align}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\frac1{n^k}\\&\geqslant\sum_{k=0}^N\binom nk\frac1{n^k}\\&=1+1+\frac{n-1}{2n}+\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{3!n^2}+\cdots+\frac{(n-1)(n-2)\ldots\bigl(n-(N-1)\bigr)}{N!n^{N-1}}\\&=1+1+\frac1{2!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)+\frac1{3!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)+\cdots\\&\phantom{=\ }+\frac1{N!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{N-1}n\right).\end{align}Therefore,\begin{align}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n&\geqslant\lim_{n\to\infty}1+1+\cdots+\frac1{N!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)+\frac1{2!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{N-1}n\right)\\&=1+1+\frac1{2!}+\cdots+\frac1{N!}\end{align}and so$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\geqslant1+1+\frac1{2!}+\cdots+\frac1{N!}.$$Since this takes place for every $N\in\mathbb N$,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\geqslant\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}.$$

Comment: $\begin{align}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n&\geqslant\lim_{n\to\infty}1+1+\cdots+\frac1{N!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)+\frac1{2!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{N-1}n\right)\\&=1+1+\frac1{2!}+\cdots+\frac1{N!}\end{align}$ How do you get that Inequality?

Comment: No. I did no use that.

Comment: But how do you know that?

Comment: How do I know *what*? Are you talking about the first inequality of my proof?

Comment: Ok, sorry, I misinterpreted somthing. It's clear now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for but:

let exp(x) be the function that satisfies the D.E.:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\exp(x) = \exp(x),\qquad \exp(0) = 1$$
hence if we do a Taylor expansion of this function we get:
$$\exp(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{x}{k!}}$$
using the limit definition of the derivative with a constant to the power x:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(k^x\right) = \lim \limits_{h \to 0}\left(\frac{k^{x+h} - k^{x}}{h}\right) = \lim \limits_{h \to 0}\left(k^{x}\left(\frac{k^{h} - 1}{h}\right)\right) = T\cdot k^{x} $$
where $T = \lim \limits_{h \to 0}\left(\frac{k^{h} - 1}{h}\right)$ is constant with respect to x. Let e be the number such that $T = 1$, trivially, $e^x = \exp(x)$.
rearranging our formula for T:
$$\lim \limits_{h \to 0}\left[\frac{e^{h} - 1}{h}\right] = 1 \Rightarrow \lim \limits_{h \to 0}\left[e =\left(1+h\right)^\frac{1}{h}\right]$$
letting $u = \frac{1}{h}$:
$$e =\lim \limits_{u \to \infty}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{u}\right)^u\right]$$
hence:
$$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\right]  = e = \exp(1) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{1}{k!}}$$